# simple vb.net calculator for adding multiple numbers

Tags: vb.net-2010

What I would like to do is how normal people add numbers i.e. they will push the number button and click on the plus button in this order

2 + 5 + 6 + 8 (calculator keeps adding the numbers up and shows the addition results). in vb.net

Answer (score 0):

I will help you with this code below:

Here is how your form should look like:

[image]

Now: add 5 buttons: "2" {Num2BUT}, "5" {Num5BUT}, "6" {Num6BUT}, "8" {Num8BUT}, "+" {PlusBUT}

and 2 TexBoxs: {ANTextBox}, {ResultTextBox}.

And here is the code:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim X1, X2 As Integer
Private Sub Num2BUT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Num2BUT.Click
    ANTextBox.Text = ANTextBox.Text + "2 "
    If X1 = 0 Then
        X1 = 2
    ElseIf X2 = 0 Then
        X2 = 2
    Else
        X2 = 2
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Num5BUT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Num5BUT.Click
    ANTextBox.Text = ANTextBox.Text + "5 "
    If X1 = 0 Then
        X1 = 5
    ElseIf X2 = 0 Then
        X2 = 5
    Else
        X2 = 5
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Num6BUT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Num6BUT.Click
    ANTextBox.Text = ANTextBox.Text + "6 "
    If X1 = 0 Then
        X1 = 6
    ElseIf X2 = 0 Then
        X2 = 6
    Else
        X2 = 6
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Num8BUT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Num8BUT.Click
    ANTextBox.Text = ANTextBox.Text + "8 "
    If X1 = 0 Then
        X1 = 8
    ElseIf X2 = 0 Then
        X2 = 8
    Else
        X2 = 8
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PlusBUT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PlusBUT.Click
    If Not ANTextBox.Text = "" Then
        If ResultTextBox.Text = "" Then
            ANTextBox.Text = ANTextBox.Text + "+ "
            If Not X1 = 0 And Not X2 = 0 Then
                ResultTextBox.Text = X1 + X2
            End If
        Else
            ANTextBox.Text = ANTextBox.Text + "+ "
            ResultTextBox.Text = ResultTextBox.Text + X2
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Note:

This code just for 4 numbers, so you have just to add more buttons and copy the code of one of these buttons and change the number (X1 = "1", X1 = "9"....ect).

Comment: sir i just want only one textbox

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it is you want to have two textboxes. One of them will show the result and the second one is used to type the numbers then the plus sign.

[image]

Here is a very simple solution:

Let's assume that TextBox2 is the textbox that will handle the number entries:

```
Dim NumberToHold As Double = 0
Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
If TextBox2.Text.Contains("+") Then
TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Replace("+", "")
TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Replace(" ", "")
NumberToHold = Val(TextBox2.Text) + NumberToHold
TextBox1.Text = NumberToHold
TextBox2.Clear()
End If
End Sub
```

Source: [Simple addition calculator- VB.NET](http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/form/simpleAdditionCalculator.html)

Comment: no sir i want to have only one textbox.. on which we enter the number and show the result. if we add four numbers , for example adding 1+2+3+4 ,first add 1 then press + button then press 2 button    after we get 3 as result..i want to show 3 on the textbox when i again press the + button

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is how your form should look like:

[image]

Now, like the first one; add 5 buttons: "2" {Num2BUT}, "5" {Num5BUT}, "6" {Num6BUT}, "8" {Num8BUT}, "+" {PlusBUT}

but now add one TexBox for result: {ANTResultTextBox}, and a **hidden** textBox {HiddenTextBox}

[image]

And here is the code:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim X1, X2 As Integer
Private Sub Num2BUT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Num2BUT.Click
    If HiddenTextBox.Text = "Plus" Then
        X2 = 2
        ANTextBox.Text = ANTextBox.Text + X2
        HiddenTextBox.Text = ""
    Else
        ANTextBox.Text = ANTextBox.Text & "2"
        X1 = 2
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Num5BUT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Num5BUT.Click
    If HiddenTextBox.Text = "Plus" Then
        X2 = 5
        ANTextBox.Text = ANTextBox.Text + X2
        HiddenTextBox.Text = ""
    Else
        ANTextBox.Text = ANTextBox.Text & "5"
        X1 = 5
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Num6BUT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Num6BUT.Click
    If HiddenTextBox.Text = "Plus" Then
        X2 = 6
        ANTextBox.Text = ANTextBox.Text + X2
        HiddenTextBox.Text = ""
    Else
        ANTextBox.Text = ANTextBox.Text & "6"
        X1 = 6
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Num8BUT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Num8BUT.Click
    If HiddenTextBox.Text = "Plus" Then
        X2 = 8
        ANTextBox.Text = ANTextBox.Text + X2
        HiddenTextBox.Text = ""
    Else
        ANTextBox.Text = ANTextBox.Text & "8"
        X1 = 8
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PlusBUT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PlusBUT.Click
    ANTextBox.Text = ANTextBox.Text + " + "
    HiddenTextBox.Text = "Plus"
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code and the form is basically designed as a textbox and a button for add, subtract, multiply and divide. The code enables addition, subtraction, multiplication and divisions of the numbers with one digit but should do in your case.

```
Public Class FrmCalculator
Dim PreviousNumber, NextNumber, DecPlace, Dec As Decimal
Dim CurrentNumber, State As String

Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
    CurrentNumber = 1
    txtNumber.Text = "1"                      
End Sub

Private Sub btn2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click
    CurrentNumber = 2
    txtNumber.Text = "2"        
End Sub

Private Sub btn3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn3.Click
    CurrentNumber = 3
    txtNumber.Text = "3"        
End Sub

Private Sub btn4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn4.Click
    CurrentNumber = 4
    txtNumber.Text = "4"        
End Sub

Private Sub btn5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn5.Click
    CurrentNumber = 5
    txtNumber.Text = "5"        
End Sub

Private Sub btn6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn6.Click
    CurrentNumber = 6
    txtNumber.Text = "6"        
End Sub

Private Sub btn7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn7.Click
    CurrentNumber = 7
    txtNumber.Text = "7"        
End Sub

Private Sub btn8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn8.Click
    CurrentNumber = 8
    txtNumber.Text = "8"        
End Sub

Private Sub btn9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn9.Click
    CurrentNumber = 9
    txtNumber.Text = "9"        
End Sub

Private Sub btnEqual_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEqual.Click
    If State = "M" Then
        NextNumber = PreviousNumber * CurrentNumber
    ElseIf State = "A" Then
        NextNumber = PreviousNumber + CurrentNumber
    ElseIf State = "S" Then
        NextNumber = PreviousNumber - CurrentNumber
    ElseIf State = "D" Then
        NextNumber = PreviousNumber / CurrentNumber            
    txtNumber.Text = NextNumber
End Sub

Private Sub btnSubtract_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubtract.Click
    PreviousNumber = CurrentNumber
    txtNumber.Clear()
    State = "S"
End Sub

Private Sub btnDivide_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDivide.Click
    PreviousNumber = CurrentNumber
    txtNumber.Clear()
    State = "D"
End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    PreviousNumber = CurrentNumber
    txtNumber.Clear()
    State = "A"
End Sub

Private Sub btnMultiply_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMultiply.Click
    PreviousNumber = CurrentNumber
    txtNumber.Clear()
    State = "M"
    'NextNumber = PreviousNumber * CurrentNumber
End Sub
```